# Flutter: Getting a more crashes on production app with this '[split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libflutter.so]'

Tags: android, ios, flutter, webview

I am encountering an error on my Android production build, but I'm not sure how to resolve it. I have researched the issue, but have not found a solution. Below is the log from the Play console crash report:

```
Thread
[FATAL:flutter/shell/platform/android/platform_view_android_jni_impl.cc(1327)] Check failed: fml::jni::CheckException(env). 

*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
pid: 0, tid: 25389 >>> com.example.app <<<

backtrace:
  #00  pc 0x00000000000705ac  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (abort+160)
  #01  pc 0x0000000000321ed4  /data/app/com.example.app-65HExU3BHjvvqXZVKhlqTQ==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!libflutter.so
```

**It is happening while flutter_webview has more then a 6000 value as a height.**

Can someone please help me resolve this error? Thank you.

Comment: It seems from the Firebase plugins. You can remove the plugins one by one to check that which plugin is producing this issue. I just removed the third-party SDK from where I was receiving this type of error.

Answer (score 0):

Check you third party plugins if causing the problem and try updating them to the latest versions.

OR

Adding this line of code in **gradle.properties** would resolve the issue.

```
android.bundle.enableUncompressedNativeLibs=false
```